# How can I apply code that calculates one element of a list to the whole list?

Tags: list-manipulation, procedural-programming

I have a problem with a while loop in Mathematica. I want to run the whole list "mFromAlice" in the while loop but I dont know how to do that. It works with the first row, which is named x in the problem just for testing. I think that I need to do a nested while loop so that I somehow can "enter" the next row, but how?

[image]

Comment: Look up "Map" and do not use "AppendTo", this is very inefficient. Use Sow and Reap instead. And please, to post code not pictures, it can be done by copy/paste. After pasting you select it and hit Ctrl K. Further, a small example that exhibits your problem will help getting a good answer.

Comment: Please do not post images of your work, especially when the images display at a size that make them difficult to read. Please post your actual Mathematica code in the form of text that can be copied and pasted into a Mathematica notebook. Without such, people who wan to helo you will have do a lot of work to reproduce your problem so they can experiment with possible solutions.

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2084223).

Answer (score 1):

Convert your code that processes one element of the list into a function and map that function over the list. Maybe something like

```
decode[x_] :=
  Module[{q, r, msg},
    q = x;
    msg = {};
    While[q ≠ 0,
      {q, r} = QuotientRemainder[q, 256];
      msg = Join[msg, {r}]];
    msg]

decode /@ mFromAlice
```

Couldn't test it because you posted an image not code.